# "TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str" when using a txt file as input

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, python-requests, get

I'm working on a python project to check username availability for Ubisoft.com. I'm doing this by making a GET request to the Ubisoft API. The usernames to check for availability are stored in a .txt file line for line.

When I run the code I get a Traceback error saying:

```
File "C:\Users\Gibbo\OneDrive\Bureaublad\Gxzs uPlay\test.py", line 24, in check
    r = requests.get("https://public-ubiservices.ubi.com/v2/profiles?nameOnPlatform=" + username + "&platformType=uplay", headers = {
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str
```

The code:

```
import requests
import json
from discord_webhook import DiscordWebhook, DiscordEmbed
import pyfiglet
from pyfiglet import figlet_format
import colorama
from colorama import Fore, Style

colorama.init()

def title():
    print(figlet_format("Gxzs's Checker!"))
    print(Fore.CYAN + 'Contact me on Discord Gxzs#3448 for Inquiries' + Fore.CYAN)

title()


def check():
    colorama.init()
    token = input("Enter token > ")
    
    username = [line.strip() for line in open("usernames.txt")]
    
    r = requests.get("https://public-ubiservices.ubi.com/v2/profiles?nameOnPlatform=" + username + "&platformType=uplay", headers = {
                'Method':'GET',
                'Authority':'public-ubiservices.ubi.com',
                'Ubi-AppId':'880650b9-35a5-4480-8f32-6a328eaa3aad',
                'Authorization': token,
                'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36',
                'Ubi-RequestedPlatformType':'uplay',
                })   
      
    userWasFound = len(r.json()['profiles']) != 0
    for i in range(5):
        print(" ")
    if userWasFound == False:
        print(username + Fore.WHITE + ' is available! :)' + Fore.WHITE)
        with open("available.txt", 'a') as f:
            f.write(f"{username}\n")
            
        webhook = DiscordWebhook(url='https://discord.com/api/webhooks/845031037838688297/N8cjHEwfhoYV-kWgSCA8L5vpMP8C32RsuPz29rTawAx7qtXqzlTV5DNuD7cKYPSSkWbw')
        embed = DiscordEmbed(title="Gxzs' Ubisoft Service", description= username + " is available or restricted", color='03b2f8')
        webhook.add_embed(embed)
        embed.set_image(url='https://media2.giphy.com/media/y8fXirTJjj6E0/giphy.gif?cid=ecf05e47foeqh9oalc5del7633idlrw3jg0jp7jo3fs7o8j3&rid=giphy.gif&ct=g')
        response = webhook.execute()
        username="Gxzs' uPlay Bot",
        avatar_url="https://i.4cdn.org/soc/1620674149395.png"

    if userWasFound == True:
        print(username + Fore.WHITE + ' is taken :( ' + Fore.WHITE)

print(Fore.CYAN + "Press ENTER to start the process..." + Fore.CYAN)
input("")
check()
```

I have tried making the code check just one username from an Input `username = input("What username to check? > ")`
and I've tried using different ways to import the .txt file such as `usernames = open('usernames.txt','r').read().splitlines()`

Comment: `username` is a list of strings and cannot be concatenated with a string (URL in your case). It looks like you need to cycle through this list and make a request for every login in `username` list.

Answer (score 0):

You describe it as you have multilpe usernames in the txt file you want to check. And it looks like the output is a list of usernames, however, your *get* implementation assumes it is a string and not a list. So to check for each username, do something like this:

```
for name in username:
    r = requests.get("https://public-ubiservices.ubi.com/v2/profiles?nameOnPlatform=" + name + "&platformType=uplay", headers ......   
  
    userWasFound = len(r.json()['profiles']) != 0
    if userWasFound:
        break
```

or whatever behaviour you want when a username is found. That way each username in the txt file is checked until it finds a username.

Answer (score 0):

Get an element in the list instead of the list.

This example takes the first element of the list.

```py
username = open('usernames.txt','r').read().splitlines()[0]
```

This prints out a list of usernames with a preceding number, so you can ask for the user to enter this number, and then get the element based on user input with `username = usernames[user_input_int]`

```py
    usernames = [line.strip() for line in open("usernames.txt")]
    for index, username in enumerate(usernames):
        print(f'{index:>3}: {username}')
```

I highly advise you to read through the [w3 docs](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp) for lists